# Buzz flange effect 

Tags: dark, knight

I was watching the dark knight soundworks video and they walk you through a lot of the process of layering sounds for the bat copter. One layer is called buzz flange and it sounds mean! I've experimented with flanging distorted low frequencies with varying success and was wondering if buzz flange is a commonly used effect and if I'm in track in attempting to recreate it?

Here is a link to the video

http://search.yahoo.com/mobile/s?rewrite=72&.tsrc=apple&first=1&p=dark+mnight+aoundworks+collection&pintl=en-gb&pcarrier=EE&pmcc=234&pmnc=30&fr=onesearch

Thanks !

Comment: FYI THere are a couple of typos in that link. As for the actual effect never really heard of 'buzz flange' as an effect type.  Maybe its just an arbitrary name. The flange is somewhat apparent in that but IMO buzz seems to be a bit misleading..

Answer (score 1):

It's from The Dark Knight Rises, http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/darkknightrises -- 4:45 in.

No, it's not a standard effect, that's just what they called it. The bit at 3:18 where they talk about using a weed whacker (or strimmer, if you prefer), attaching stuff to it and recording that, well I think these are those sounds - they call them 'buzz flange' and 'bat moan'. Looks like they've made a bunch of different groups of sounds each with different post-processing applied.

We can only speculate of course, but it sounds like various types of distortion and amplitude modulation with some doppler to add movement. I think much of the character of these sound is in the recordings themselves though, not the processing.